# Disable HTML (Text) Tab in Post Editor

Tags: admin, hooks, tinymce, editor, wp-editor

I am attempting to disable the Text tab in the post editor but not having any luck.

[image]

The first thing I want to do is set the Visual editor to be the default but this code does not work (it is being called from a MU plugin):

```
apply_filters( 'wp_default_editor', 'tinymce' );
```

Next, I want to be able to completely hide the 'Visual' and 'Text' tabs but I don't see and hooks I could use to accomplish this.I really don't want to resort to CSS/JS to do it.

Comment: I figured out my first problem with setting the default. It should have been add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it as well :-)

Comment: But there is still the second part of my question. I was curious if there is a better way than CSS/JS to get rid of the tabs.

Comment: AH OK. Then you should add your comment as an [edit] to your question :-)

Comment: please let me know where are the relevant files in wordpress files. i cant locate the right .js , .css and plugin file u mention

Answer (score 10):

I was hunting for a way to do this, and no-one seems to mention the wp_editor_settings filter.
This worked for me:

```
function my_editor_settings($settings) {
$settings['quicktags'] = false;
return $settings;
}

add_filter('wp_editor_settings', 'my_editor_settings');
```

Comment: Thanks. This code seem to work for me. Is it possible the make it work for all users roles except Administrator?

Comment: This isn't tested, but I suspect if you modified the above code as follows:
`if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
$settings['quicktags'] = false;
}
return $settings;
`
It might work

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve both defaulting to the Visual editor and hiding the tabs with the following code.

Dumped the following in plugin file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', array($this, 'default_editor') );
```

Hide the tabs with this javascript:

```
$('.wp-editor-tabs').remove();
```

Or hide it with CSS:

```
.wp-editor-tabs{display:none;}
```